# MySQL: Create consistent dump of audit tables

Tags: mysql

I have set up a system whose purpose it is to generate incremental dumps of our production data to our data warehouse. "Incremental" in this sense means that we can "synchronize" the production database with our data warehouse every minute or so without having to generate a full dump. Instead, we are just dumping and inserting the new/changed data.

On our replication save, I have set up a system where every relevant table of our production database has one insert `TRIGGER` and one update `TRIGGER`. These copy every row which is inserted or updated into an "audit table" in a different schema. This audit schema contains tables with the same structure as the production tables, but no indexes, and by using those `TRIGGER`s the audit tables will only contain the new or updated rows since the last export.

At the moment I'm using the `mysql` command line client to do the following for each of these audit tables:

1. `LOCK TABLES table WRITE`
2. `SELECT * FROM table`
3. `DELETE FROM table`
4. `UNLOCK TABLES`

I then pipe the output to some other scripts for further processing.

Now this works perfectly fine, **however** it creates the problem that while the state of every individual table will be consistent, the entire set of tables won't be. For example, if I have a `clicks` table and an `impressions` table and there is a 1 minute delay between dumping the former and the latter, the entire dump will be in a state which is inconsistent, obviously.

Now my question is: How do I do the following:

1. Lock ALL tables
2. Generate dumps for ALL tables
3. Delete all data from ALL tables
4. Unlock tables

I cannot use the `mysql` command line client because I cannot keep the lock across different sessions, and each table requires a new command. Also, I checked `mysqldump` which allows dumping multiple tables at a time, but I didn't find a way to delete all data from the tables before releasing the locks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the first two points the command could be this one :

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p DATABASENAME > nameofdumpfile.sql
```

Since it is not possible to perform step 3 and 4 without releasing the lock, at least with mysqldump utility, why don't copy all the tables into another database (backup db) and then export the dump file from it ?

```
CREATE DATABASE backupdb;
USE originaldb;
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

keep this prompt(Prompt 1) open and then clone the database from another command prompt(Prompt 2) :

```
   mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p originaldb | mysql -u backup -p password backupdb;
```

Drop the original database from the Prompt 1 :

```
USE backupdb;
DROP DATABASE originaldb;
```

Then restore the empty database back with its original name (note the -d flag ) :

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p backupdb | mysql -u backup -p password originaldb;
```

This could be an example of a workaround that you can apply to achieve what you need.